# Using Figma Variants from React Amplify project

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, aws-amplify, figma

I was able to override props of **FAQItem** component present in [AWS Amplify UI Kit](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1047600760128127424) as per [amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/uibuilder/override/#extend-generated-code-via-component-prop)

I now wish to create a variant of **FAQItem**  in Figma and use it in my amplify app. The intent is to learn how to use figma variants from amplify. To achieve this -

I created a variant of FAQItem in Figma by clicking on "Add new Variant". A new variant with name "Variant2" was created. I changed the Title of variant2 FAQItem so that it visually appears different from the Default variant.

I synced the Figma file with my amplify project followed by `amplify pull`. Below snippet shows shows how the FAQItem variant was used in React app.

```
import {FAQItem} from './ui-components'
...
...                
<FAQItem  property1= "Variant2" />
```

However this is not working and it renders the default variant.
What would be the correct way to render FAQItem variant ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello The same is happening to me, I tested with the default HeroLayout1 because the variant came with the figma template but is only displaying the default variant (Light) instead of the dark one.

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { AmplifyProvider } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import awsconfig from '../src/aws-exports';
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

//Custom UI Components
import { HeroLayout1 } from '../src/ui-components';

function Home() {
  return (
    <AmplifyProvider>
      <HeroLayout1 mode='Dark' />
    </AmplifyProvider>
  )
}

export default withAuthenticator(Home);
```

Comment: I tried and observed the same with HeroLayout1. It is a good idea to use HeroLayout1 since the variant was already present in Figma template. Am wondering if this is a bug, or there is a different method to specify a variant. Thanks @Humbert for trying this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to get my Figma variants to process in React, until I realized the variants ARE rendering correctly when I specify *all* the key/values of the variant. But when I only specify one property of a multi-variant component, none of it is honored and overridden. If the variant only contains one property, then of course specifying a value for that property works.

Example

1. <StepIcon size="small" overrides={{"icon": { src: MathIcon }}}/>
2. ```
     `<StepIcon size="small" color='Light' overrides={{"icon": { src: MathIcon }}}/>`
   ```

My base variant includes a large size and dark color. In #1 above, when I specify size="small", it still shows large variant, ignoring that I specified the size=small. But in #2, it indeed shows small size variant (in light color). But if I change #1 to

```
<StepIcon size="small" color='Dark/Light' overrides={{"icon": { src: MathIcon }}}/>
```

it will now show the same icon in small size, since I also included the color property.
Since the HeroLayout1 only has one variant property, this probably doesn't fix your original issue, but it may help someone else.